# IE & Edge Certificate Revoked

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, ssl, https, microsoft-edge

I am having an issue with a website where IE & MS Edge & Chrome all believe that the certificate is revoked (firefox works fine)

Error from IE:

```
This organisation's certificate has been revoked.

Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to trick you or intercept any data you send to the server.
```

I have run check on SSLLabs, and the only problem i can see there is that it uses SHA1 hashes. Am i just seeing this error because of the SHA1 RSA Signatures?

URL: https://www.gunemporium.com.au/

Comment: This question was useful to diagnose my issues, SSLLabs test uri is: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, SHA-1 is completely broken, and does not provide any effective encryption.

Comment: It's strange that chrome and edge on 2 PC's here all same version's, one works, and one shows cert error,

Answer (score 0):

I would more suggest that there is some SSL intercepting middlebox or AV software involved which changes the certificate and the issuer of the certificate. IE and Chrome both use the same CA store and proxy settings while Firefox has their own settings which would explain why you see it with IE and Chrome but not Firefox on the same PC and why you don't see it on another PC.

I would suggest to have a look at the certificate details (subject, issuer, fingerprint) and chain and compare what you see in Firefox with what you see in IE/Chrome.